# Numeric time derivative in a .dat file

Tags: python, math, numeric, tabular, derivative

I have a long 3-columns table of numerical data. For example, a small piece of it looks like this:

```
-5.3986816409999996e+00 8.3394692357616169e-23 2.2891221151890116e-23
-5.3984375003749996e+00 8.1834931317429596e-23 2.7962314960022732e-23
-5.3981933597499996e+00 7.9967086078053667e-23 3.2928354334362533e-23
-5.3979492191249996e+00 7.7798165392355974e-23 3.7770639137136620e-23
-5.3977050784999996e+00 7.5336312057849817e-23 4.2470933118491389e-23
-5.3974609378749996e+00 7.2590772420102232e-23 4.7011532627697938e-23
-5.3972167972499996e+00 6.9571861716728761e-23 5.1375333330996674e-23
-5.3969726566249996e+00 6.6290925391538841e-23 5.5545894684658167e-23
-5.3967285159999996e+00 6.2760296523720059e-23 5.9507501919987393e-23
-5.3964843753749996e+00 5.8993249531280359e-23 6.3245225306694521e-23
-5.3962402347499996e+00 5.5003950322868833e-23 6.6744976470308050e-23
```

To be clear, the first column shows the time(t) and the other two indicate some other variables both as functions of time, let say f(t) and g(t). I want to calculate the time-derivative of each function and save it in a new data file. I'm not sure how should I handle this numerically. Any idea?

Comment: `df/dt=1/Delta_t*(f[n]-f[n-1])`   is one approximation of derivative, where `Delta_t` is your timestep. You can find other approximations for derivatives (centered, higher-order, etc). Play around with known functions and see what you get

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking for a handy function in Python to do it for me.

Comment: Negative times?  That's unusual.  I'd also worry about the small values for the functions.  They look small enough to be considered zero from an IEEE floating point number standpoint.  "Handy Python function"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple solution. Use `numpy` package and `numpy.diff` gives you the derivative.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for a first-order estimation, you can use δx/δt ≈ Δx / Δt.

```
# import file
t = []; f = []; g = []
for line in open('in_file.dat'):
    line = line.split()
    t.append(float(line[0]))
    f.append(float(line[1]))
    g.append(float(line[2]))

# calculate approximate derivatives
dt = [] # times for derivative values
df = [] # approximate derivative of f
dg = [] # approximate derivative of g
for i in range(len(t) - 1):
    delta_t = t[i + 1] - t[i]  # time between points
    dt.append(t[i] + delta_t * 0.5)  # midway between points
    df.append((f[i - 1] - f[i]) / delta_t)
    dg.append((g[i - 1] - g[i]) / delta_t)

# save to new file
f = '{:23.16e} {:23.16e} {:23.16e}\n'
out_lines = [f.format(dt[i], df[i], dg[i]) for i in range(len(dt))]
open('out_file.dat', 'w').writelines(out_lines)
```

Note that the derivatives have time indexes midway between points. Consequently, the new time and derivatives lists will be 1 element shorter than the inputs. This is normal, though some more advanced methods will have 1-to-1 times. Note also that the output file format is up to you. I've just used approximately the same format as above.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(t) - 1):
    delta_t = t[i + 1] - t[i]  # time between points
    dt.append(t[i] + delta_t * 0.5)  # midway between points
    df.append((f[i + 1] - f[i]) / delta_t)
    dg.append((g[i + 1] - g[i]) / delta_t)
```

correction from - to + ==> f[i **+** 1] - f[i]) / delta_t